# SQL Server Simple SUM query not returning expected results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've searched through some other answers but haven't gotten this to work how I expect.

My query:

```
SELECT 
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(18),[Trx_Date],110) AS Date
  ,[TRX_TYPE]
  ,SUM([QUAN]) AS QUANt
  FROM [VM].[dbo].[INVTRX]
  WHERE SKU='7342761'  AND TRX_TYPE!='S' AND TRX_DATE BETWEEN '12-15-2016' AND '12-18-2016' AND ID_CONT=557
  GROUP BY QUAN, Trx_Type, TRX_DATE
```

My Results:

> Date ---- TRX_TYPE ---- QUANt
>
> 12-15-2016 ---- PT ---- 48.0000
>
> 12-16-2016 ---- PT ---- 78.0000
>
> 12-16-2016 ---- PT ---- 90.0000

What I am looking for:

> Date ---- TRX_TYPE ---- QUANt
>
> 12-15-2016 ---- PT ---- 48.0000
>
> 12-16-2016 ---- PT ---- 168.0000

Also, a bonus question:  How do I format tables on Stackoverflow?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: remove `QUAN` from `group by`.

Comment: Thanks, I actually just added that while I was trying various fixes.  I did remove it, but the bigger issue was using the converted date as pointed out below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(18),[Trx_Date],110) AS Date
  ,[TRX_TYPE]
  ,SUM([QUAN]) AS QUANt
  FROM [VM].[dbo].[INVTRX]
  WHERE SKU='7342761'  AND TRX_TYPE!='S' AND TRX_DATE BETWEEN '12-15-2016' AND '12-18-2016' AND ID_CONT=557
  GROUP BY Trx_Type, Trx_Date;
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly.  Such an easy oversight.  I will accept your answer as soon as it lets me (10  minutes)

Answer (score 1):

You would seem to have a time component on the date.  I would suggest just converting to `date` rather than a string:

```
SELECT CAST([Trx_Date] AS Date), TRX_TYPE
       SUM(QUAN) AS QUANT
FROM [VM].[dbo].[INVTRX] i
WHERE SKU = '7342761' AND
      TRX_TYPE <> 'S' AND
      TRX_DATE >= '2016-12-15' AND
      TRX_DATE < '2016-12-19' AND
      ID_CONT = 557
GROUP BY CAST([Trx_Date] AS Date), Trx_Type;
```

Notes:

- Convert to a `date` to remove the time component.
- You need to repeat the expression in the `GROUP BY`.
- For date constants use ISO standard formats, such as YYYYMMDD or YYYY-MM-DD.
- If your date has a time component component (which it appears to have), then don't use `BETWEEN`.
- Only include the unaggregated columns in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information, it is helpful.  May I ask why one should not use between when the date has a time component?  Additionally is there a preference for <> versus !=   ?  I am clearly in the learning stage and would like to adhere to standards when possible.